# Is there any possible to achieve dynamic batch size in Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, batchsize

In order to reduce the difficulty of the code, I allow to restart the Spark Streaming system to use new batch size, but need to keep the previous progress (allowing to lose the batch being processed).

If I use `checkpoint` in Spark Streaming, it can't change all configurations when the application restarts.

So I want to implement this function by modifying the source code, but I don't know where to start. Hope to give some guidance and tell me the difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about the batch size I'm assuming that you are asking about spark streaming and not structured streaming.

There is a way to programmatically set the value for your batch interval, refer [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/StreamingContext.html) link for documentation.

the constructor of `StreamingContext` accepts the `duration` class's object which defines the batch interval.

you can pass batch interval size by hardcoding it in the code, which will require you to build the jar file every time when you need to change batch interval, instead, you can bring it from a config file, this way you don't need to build the code every time.

Note: You have to set this property in the applications's config file, not in the spark's config file.

You can change the config for batch interval and restart the application, this will not cause any problems with respect to checkpointing.

```
val sparkConf: SparkConf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName("app-name")
  .setMaster("app-master")

val ssc: StreamingContext = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(config.getInt("batch-interval")))
```

Cheers!!